# How to get user sort order with CNContact API

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, cncontact

I know that I can sort with CNContacts like this:

```
let fetch = CNContactFetchRequest(...)
fetch.sortOrder = .UserDefault
```

The question is: how do I find what *is* that sort order? Apart from some hacky heuristic of examining what comes back from the fetch enumeration.

There is an old ABPersonGetSortOrdering() call that will probably stay around for a while, but surely there is a CNContact way to do it.

Answer (score 14):

`ABPersonGetSortOrdering()` was deprecated in iOS 9.0: use [[CNContactsUserDefaults sharedDefaults] sortOrder]

let sortOrder = CNContactsUserDefaults.sharedDefaults().sortOrder

Comment: This really works, thanks! Just wondering that CNContactsUserDefaults is not properly documented. I hope it's not an internal API?

Comment: It's not: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactsuserdefaults/1402779-sortorder

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

Using the default sort Order :

```
let sortOrder = CNContactsUserDefaults.shared().sortOrder
```

For Custom Sort Order i.e.

```
let customSortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.givenName
```